# Hook function not called with async modification

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have the following model with hook

```
User.init({ },{ 
    hooks: {
        beforeUpdate: async (user, options) => {
            console.log('updated');
            // some async job here with await
        }
    }
});
```

Now I am trying to update a row:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ ... });
user.balance = 1000002;
await user.save();
```

Above is not triggering the hook for some reason.
If I remove await and just call

```
user.save();
```

then the hook is called. How can I modify instance asynchronously while having hook triggered?

Comment: neither `user.increment('balance')` is triggering hook and with or without `await`.

Comment: Did you try beforeSave? There is also sync attribute which differ hooks to sync and async.